# Angular2 update URL on property changes (with browser history)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

Say that I have a `Component` that acts as a sort of master detail. I would like the URL reflect the changes of the detail-part without reloading the entire `Component`.

This is what I have:

**home.routing.ts**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { ItemListComponent } from "./item-list.component";

const homeRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "home",
        component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: ":categoryId",
                component: HomeComponent
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: "home",
        component: HomeComponent
    }
];

export const homeRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes);
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";

...

@Component({
    template: `
            <div *ngFor="let category of categories">
                <span (click)="onSelect(category)">{{category.title}}</span>
            </div>
            <item-list></item-list>
    `,
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    categories: Category[];
    selectedCategoryId: string;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getCategories();

        // Update selectedCategoryId if it is set in the URL
        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            this.selectedCategoryId = params["categoryId"];
        })
    }

    onSelect(category: Category) {
        this.selectedCategoryId = category.id;

        // This will trigger a change in the item-list component and the
        // items will be loaded based on the selected category. 
        // What can I do here to reflect the change of selected category
        // in the URL?
    }

    getCategories() {
        ...
        this.categories = categoriesFromRestAPI;
    }
}
```

**item-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

...

@Component({
    selector: "item-list",
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="categoryId">
            <div *ngFor="let item of items">
                <span>{{item.text}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class ItemListComponent {
    private _categoryId: string;
    items: Item[];

    constructor() {
    }

    @Input()
    set categoryId(categoryId: string) {
        this._categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    get categoryId() {
        return this._categoryId;
    }

    getItems() {
        // Get items based on this._categoryId;
        items = itemsFromRestApi;
    }
}
```

When a user selected a category, how can I reflect that in the URL, and update the browser history so that back button will work? Is it possible? I have asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854968/angular2-routing-within-feature-module), but using the router instead. I think both options could be used in different scenarios, but I just can't get them right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you navigate to the same route using `this.router.navigate(...)` or `<a [routerLink]="..."` where only parameter values change, then the component instances are reused and the browser history is updated.

Comment: Ok. So I should be using a route like `/home` or `home?categoryId=123` instead in this case then?

Comment: That way the parameter is a query parameter. What you want is route parameter. `/home/123` would match your route configuration.

Comment: But how could I cover the initial case when no category is selected? That would be `/home`. And then with a selected category `/home/12` which will be another route. Both routes should load the same master/detail view.

Comment: You can add another route with an empty path and the same component `children: [
            {
                path: "", pathMatch: 'full',
                component: HomeComponent
            },

            {
                path: ":categoryId",
                component: HomeComponent
            }
        ]`. In this case the `HomeComponent` will be destroyed and recreated when you switch between these routes (not when only the `categoryId` changes)

Comment: Yeah that was it! As long as I declare the routes as child routes, the components will be reused. Thank you!